# BlueZ-pyDbus 2 client connected in HCI0

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, dbus, bluez

I have successfully made connection to 2 BLE server simultaneously via pyDbus. However when i want to read/write to first BLE Server, i am unable to do so. I checked on this issue and find out the second BLE server connection overcomes the first one. Attached is a snippet of the code:

```
def device_Init(macAdd):

     adapter = bus.get('org.bluez','/org/bluez/hci0')
     dev = bus.get('org.bluez','/dev_(the macAdd)')
     mngr = bus.get('org.bluez','/')
    
     dev.Connect()
```

then of course when need to disconnect then issue `dev.Disconnect()`

How to separate the connecting, read/write and disconnect part between two connected device? I have tried to create another function but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `dev` property gets overwritten when you create it a second time with a different device address. You could have a second variable for the second device.

However, a more pythonic way of doing this would probably be to have a class that you instantiate twice.

Here is an example of what this could look like:

```py
from time import sleep
import pydbus

bus = pydbus.SystemBus()

mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')

def get_characteristic_path(dev_path, uuid):
    mng_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mng_objs:
        chr_uuid = mng_objs[path].get('org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1', {}).get('UUID')
        if path.startswith(dev_path) and chr_uuid == uuid:
           return path

class MyRemoteDevice:
    CHAR_UUID = 'e95dda90-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8'

    def __init__(self, mac_addr):
        device_path = f"/org/bluez/hci0/dev_{mac_addr.replace(':', '_')}"
        self.device = bus.get('org.bluez', device_path)

        # Placeholder for characteristic details
        self.characteristic = None

    def _get_gatt_details(self):
        char_path = get_characteristic_path(self.device._path,
                                            MyRemoteDevice.CHAR_UUID)
        self.characteristic = bus.get('org.bluez', char_path)


    def connect(self):
        self.device.Connect()
        # Check GATT services have been resolved before continuing
        while not self.device.ServicesResolved:
            sleep(0.25)
        self._get_gatt_details()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.device.Disconnect()

    def read(self):
        return self.characteristic.ReadValue({})

    def write(self, new_value):
        self.characteristic.WriteValue(new_value, {})


my_first_dev = MyRemoteDevice('11:22:33:44:55:66')
my_second_dev = MyRemoteDevice('22:33:44:55:66:77')

my_first_dev.connect()
my_second_dev.connect()

print(my_first_dev.read())
print(my_second_dev.read())

my_first_dev.disconnect()
my_second_dev.disconnect()
```

Comment: Thanks again.Just wondering.Is it possible to use 2 bluetooth (RPI & USB Bluetooth dongle) at the same time (in example HCI0 & HCI1) in pyDbus. Secondly how  feasible it is to create a GATT server with pyDbus? Just curios