Connect a raspberry pi to a bluetooth thermal printer with Bluez API
I am trying to connect a thermal printer to a raspberry pi 4 running Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) using the Bluez API.
So far I managed to pair with the printer, but now I am struggling to connect the raspi with it. Since the printer uses a Bluetooth's Serial Port Profile, I managed to connect with it via CLI with rfcomm, but I want to do it 100% programatically in a sort of wizard embedded in a django application.
I understood I first need to configure the profile, which I apparently did with:
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
device_path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx"

manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/org/bluez"),
                        "org.bluez.ProfileManager1")


manager.RegisterProfile(device_path, "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", {})

When I try to connect to the printer via connect()I get the following error:
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable: br-connection-profile-unavailable

I would really appretiate some help on that issue.

The first argument of RegisterProfile should be the object path to where you created an interface for org.bluez.Profile. An example of doing this is at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-profile. However, for what you are doing it will probably be easier to use the built in Python socket functionality. Look at the Python Sockets Client example at: http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

Thanks a lot @ukBaz ! It worked with a BT4.0 Thermal printer. Do you know if python-socketswould also connect to a BLE thermal printer like this one ? https://learn.adafruit.com/ble-cat-thermal-printer-with-memento/overview

The "cat" printer you linked to seems to Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) rather than Bluetooth Classic so the python-socket library will not work. python-socket library uses the UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is the official UUID for Serial Port Profile (SPP) on Classic. The "cat" printer seems to have the GATT service of ff00 and the characteristic of ff02 which are common (but not official) values for doing serial with BLE. With GATT you don't need RegisterProfile

An example of reading and writing to BLE GATT using Python would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/63556387/7721752.  The full 128-bit characteristic UUID would be 0000ff02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. You can test with a generic scanning and exploration tool such as nRF Connect

Thanks @ukBaz ! Is it possible to bind a socket to a /dev/rfcommX serial device?

I'm not sure I understand the context of the question "Is it possible to bind a socket to a /dev/rfcommX serial device?". This seems to be unrelated to the original question. I think you have solved the original question so you could write up your solution as an answer. Then create a new question for your BLE printer which would allow you to explain more fully what you are having problems with.

I managed to connect to the BT4.0 printer using python-sockets following the good advices of @ukBaz:
dongle_addr = xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (MAC-address of bluetooth adapter)
port = 1

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((dongle_addr, port))

try:
    s.connect((printer_addr, port))
    print(f'Device {printer.name} connected')
except Exception as error:
    print(type(error).__name__, error)
    s.close()

s.send(b"Hello World\n")

I managed to connect to the BLE printer based on the code from here.
Thanks @ukBaz for your help !
